# How to add all of these symbols (" " ! ? ; " , . / ” “ ' ) in preg_replace pattern in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have:

```
$input = str_replace('/all these symbols/', "", $input);
```

Can't really understand the pattern syntax for `preg_match` and `preg_replace`. Sometimes people use `'+ - * ^ $ \s'` and different kind of brackets there. Tried to read the manual, but don't really get it. Can i find somewhere more clear information about all the possibilities of the preg syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://lzone.de/examples/PHP%20preg_match and here you can try it online http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just put those characters into character class as shown in below example:

```
$replaced = preg_replace("/[“”!?;\",.\/”“']/u", " ", "hello!?; “how are you”");
print_r($replaced);
```

The output:

```
hello     how are you
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use squared brackets, just have to escape the right chars:

```
echo preg_replace('/[“”!?;",.\/”“\']/', '', 'a!b?c');
```